# Dynamic Pivot to show how voters voted

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, pivot

Here is the table structure:

```
Election
ElectionId ElectionName
1          12P
2          11G

History
ElectionId VoterId HowVoted
1          1       Rep
2          2       Dem
1          2       Non 

Voter
VoterId VoterName
1       Bill Smith
2       John Hearst
```

I want the output like this:

```
VoterName   12P  11P  note: Election names change so need to be pivoted dynamically
Bill Smith  Rep  Null
John Hearst Non  Dem
```

I basically need to pivot the ElectionNames to the Column Names and then show how the voter voted in the row.    Suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Please show sample data and desired results. Also, please use `{}` to properly highlight code samples instead of `<br>` tags.

Comment: you did not show what you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using dynamic SQL like so:

```
-- Get column names
DECLARE @Columns VARCHAR(MAX);  SET @Columns = '';
SELECT @Columns = @Columns + ', [' + ElectionName + ']' FROM Election;
SET @Columns = SUBSTRING(@Columns, 3, LEN(@Columns)) -- Remove the leading ', '

-- Declare dynamic SQL
DECLARE @sql VARCHAR(MAX);
SET @sql = 'WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT VoterName, ElectionName, HowVoted
    FROM Election e
        INNER JOIN History h ON e.ElectionId = h.ElectionId
        INNER JOIN Voter v ON v.VoterId = h.VoterId
)
SELECT [VoterName], ' + @Columns + 'FROM CTE
PIVOT (MAX(HowVoted) FOR ElectionName IN ('+ @Columns + ')) AS p'

-- Run dynamic SQL
EXEC(@sql)
```

Comment: Thanks, it works!  Follow-up question, if i needed to add a where clause to the CTE such as WHERE PRECINCTID = @PrecinctId.  Am I opening myself up to injection attacks with this?  If so is there a work around?

Comment: Take a look at [sp_executesql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188001.aspx) with parameters.